# Xlookup with dates and sum formula in EXCEL

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, xlookup

I am trying to figure out a formula to find the sum of hours worked for each worker per month and also per project. I am pretty sure the XLOOKUP, AND/IF, and SUBTotal could be useful but I am not exactly sure how to combine it all. Here are the exact data.

Lookup values for each employee (Column A),
Lookup values for each project per employee (Column B),
Lookup values for each Timesheet period (column C) format: 2022/06/03,
Then sum the total hours work of each employee, per project per month (Column D)

Thanks in advance!

I tried the XLOOKUP formula
AND formula for the dates
SUBTOTAL formula for the hours.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sumifs solves your problem

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$12,$A$2:$A$12,$A15,$B$2:$B$12,$B15,$C$2:$C$12,">="&DATE(2022,7,1);$C$2:$C$12,"<="&DATE(2022,7,31))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using **[SUMPRODUCT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)** as well

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C20`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A20=$A$2:$A$13)*(B20=$B$2:$B$13)*(TEXT($C$2:$C$13,"mm/yyyy")="06/2022")*($D$2:$D$13))
```

---

Note: Use cell reference like as below to make it dynamic

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C20`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A20=$A$2:$A$13)*($B20=$B$2:$B$13)*(TEXT($C$2:$C$13,"mm/yyyy")=TEXT(C$18,"mm/yyyy"))*($D$2:$D$13))
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses O365 functions to generate an array solution. The reference dates are generated in cell `H2` as a `1x3` array and formatted as date as follows: `mmm-yy` (not relevant for the calculation, just for visualization):

```
=EDATE(DATE(2022,6,1),SEQUENCE(1,3,0))
```

then in `H3` put the following formula and expand it to the right, **no need to expand it down**:

```
=LET(set, $A$2:$D$13, lkup, $F$3:$G$8, SOM, H2, projects, INDEX(set,,1), 
  employes, INDEX(set,,2),timesheets, INDEX(set,,3), hours, INDEX(set,,4),
  MAP(INDEX(lkup,,1), INDEX(lkup,,2), LAMBDA(prj,empl, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
    SUM(FILTER(hours, (projects =prj) * (employes = empl) * (timesheets >= SOM) 
     * (timesheets <= EOM),0))
  )))
)
```

where `LET` is used for **easy reading** and composition.

**Note**: Instead of `SUM/FILTER` you can use one of the following options too:

```
SUMPRODUCT(hours, (projects =prj) * (employes = empl) * (timesheets >= SOM) 
 * (timesheets <= EOM))
```

or

```
SUMPRODUCT(hours, N(projects =prj), N(employes = empl), N(timesheets >= SOM), 
  N(timesheets <= EOM))
```

or just `SUM`:

```
SUM(hours * (projects =prj) * (employes = empl) * (timesheets >= SOM) 
  * (timesheets <= EOM))
```

it is a matter of preference.

Here is the output:
[image: sample output]

If you wonder if it is possible to **avoid expanding to the right the formula**, so we can have the entire result in just one formula, yes it is possible.

**Alternative 1**: Using `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK`:

```
=LET(set, A2:D13, lkup, F3:G8, SOMs, H2:J2, projects, INDEX(set,,1), 
  employes, INDEX(set,,2),timesheets, INDEX(set,,3), hours, INDEX(set,,4),
  DROP(REDUCE(0,SOMs, LAMBDA(acc, SOM, HSTACK(acc, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
  MAP(INDEX(lkup,,1), INDEX(lkup,,2), LAMBDA(prj, empl,
   SUM(hours * (projects =prj) * (employes = empl) * (timesheets >= SOM) 
    * (timesheets <= EOM))
  )))))),,1)
)
```

**Alternative 2**: Using `TEXTSPLIT/TEXTJOIN`:

```
=LET(set, A2:D13, lkup, F3:G8, SOMs, H2:J2, projects, INDEX(set,,1), 
  employes, INDEX(set,,2),timesheets, INDEX(set,,3), hours, INDEX(set,,4),
  byC, BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0), 
  mp, MAP(INDEX(lkup,,1), INDEX(lkup,,2), LAMBDA(prj, empl,
     SUM(hours * (projects =prj) * (employes = empl) * (timesheets >= SOM) 
      * (timesheets <= EOM))
  )), TEXTJOIN(",",, mp)
  ))),
  TRANSPOSE(1*TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",, byC), ",", ";"))
)
```

**Note**: Under both Alternatives there is no need to use `$`-notation in the ranges.